# How to show HD Webcam

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I'm new to AS, so please write the code in an easy way to understand: I am making a webcam application in Flash CS5 (using ActionScript 3), and have searched the interweb finding either tutorials that don't work or show the webcam in the wrong size, which I would like to be 1280p. Any help would be appreciated.

Current Code:

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
var vid:Video = new Video(); 
vid.attachCamera(cam); 
addChild(vid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's import the things we need and define a few constants we need later on

```
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.Video;

const CAMERA_WIDTH:uint = 1280;
const CAMERA_HEIGHT:uint = 720;
const CAMERA_FPS:uint = 12;
```

Now we look up what cameras we have connected to our System and trace them out, just as information

```
// Let's take a look what Cameras are available
var cams:Array = Camera.names;
var camLength:uint = Camera.names.length;
for (var i:uint = 0; i < camLength; ++i)
    trace(i, cams[i]);
```

Now that we know which cameras are installed we select one, there are basically 2 ways

```
// get systems standard camera device
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); // if you don't put a parameter into the getCamera method, it automatically takes the systems standard
```

Or take a specific camera which we read out before (oddly this wants a string as parameter instead of a number)

```
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera("0"); // takes the first camera from the Camera.names array
```

to set the resolution of the selected camera you call the setMode method as seen here (width, height and frames per second), in this case we use our defined constants for that

```
camera.setMode(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, CAMERA_FPS);
```

to display your pretty face on the stage you need a video, following code should be selfexplanatory

```
var video:Video = new Video(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
video.attachCamera(camera);
addChild(video);
```

that's it

Comment: It came up with these errors: `Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 2, Line 14 1151: A conflict exists with definition cams in namespace internal.`, and, 
`Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 2, Line 151151: A conflict exists with definition camLength in namespace internal.`

Comment: whoops i accidently defined those 2 variables twice, i'll edit it in the code above

Comment: How would I position the camera output (x=152.50, y=147.45)?

Comment: by setting the video x and y properties. 
video.x = 152.5
video.y = 147.45